# Oracle ATG: Select and Delete all list items from BCC cosole on single click

Tags: atg, oracle-commerce

Oracle ATG OOTB dones not provide a option to select all list type items and deleting all in a single click.

Ex: Create a BCC project, Go to any particular product and you will find many SKU's for that product(if it was already added). There is a "-" symbol to delete against eack and every SKU to delete but i wanted to delete the SKU's that the count is 500 on my catalog where i can not click in "-" symbol 500 times.

Pleas help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of ATG are you using, since customising the BCC interface is different depending on which version you are using. I'm not saying it is possible but we can't help you if you don't give us enough information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have at least 2 options:

1. The assets management in the BCC, It should named like 'Site
   Assets' or 'Browse Assets', it supports multi-select:

[image]

2. Use the startSQLRepository. You should create several fake
   datasource and an xml include of a lot of remove-item, then create
   an BCC project with startSQLRepository, deploy it in BCC then you
   are all done. For more information, see the docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGRepositoryGuide/html/s1207importingtoaversionedrepository01.html)
   and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23507_01/Platform.20073/RepositoryGuide/html/s1107startsqlrepositoryscriptargument01.html).

Comment: Not sure if either of these answers the original question. The OP wants to delete many skus related to a single product. The `Asset Browse` option you provide here doesn't allow you to search for the skus based on a parent product. Your `startSQLRepository` approach doesn't give them an interface to work with so not sure that is an option either.